# Is this limit correctly computed?

Tags: calculus, limits

Here is the function:

\begin{align*}
u(x,y,z)={}&\int_0^1\frac{\tau}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+(z-\tau)^2}}\mathrm{d}\tau={} \\
{}={}&\sqrt{x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2}-\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}-{} \\
&{}+z\log\left|\frac{z-1+\sqrt{x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2}}{z+\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\right|,
\end{align*}

where the last equality holds outside the $z$ axis, whereas on the $z$ axis the expression is just the first two terms, outside $\{0\}\times\{0\}\times[0,1]$, of course. I am now pretty convinced I calculated this correctly, and [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdt%28sqrt%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%2B%28z-t%29%5E2%29-zlog%28z-t%2Bsqrt%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%2B%28z-t%29%5E2%29%29%29) agrees if I take the absolute values out, but since they are in a log when I differentiate they just go away, so it's like confirming in any case. I state this because [my Higher Analysis course notes](http://www.matapp.unimib.it/~stefanom/didattica/matematica/anSup2013-2014/appunti/AnalisiSuperioreAppuntiInItinere.pdf) have different signs in various points, and the same goes for [this pdf](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/gantumur/math580f13/dirichlet.pdf). Now I want to take the limit for $z\to0^+$ along surfaces of the form $(e^{-\frac\alpha{2z}}\cos\theta,e^{-\frac\alpha{2z}}\sin\theta,z)$. This is because I want to test its continuity at the origin. The two square roots converge to 1 and 0 respectively, since both $z$ and $e^{\frac\alpha{2z}}$ go to 0. I'm then left with the log, which I split into a sum of logs -- well yeah a difference since I have a quotient inside it. So here I go:

\begin{multline*}
\lim_{z\to0^+}\left[-z\log\left(z-1+\sqrt{e^{-\frac{\alpha}{z}}+(z-1)^2}\right)+z\log\left(z+\sqrt{e^{-\frac{\alpha}{z}}+z^2}\right)\right]={} \\
=\lim_{z\to0^+}z\left[-\log\left(z-1+\sqrt{1+z^2-2z+e^{-\frac{\alpha}{z}}}\right)+\log\left(z+e^{-\frac{\alpha}{2z}}\sqrt{1+\frac{z^2}{e^{-\frac{\alpha}{z}}}}\right)\right]={} \\
\lim_{z\to0^+}z\left[-\log\left(z-1+1+\frac{z^2-2z+e^{-\frac{\alpha}{z}}}{2}+o\left(z^2-2z+e^{-\frac{\alpha}{z}}\right)\right)\right.+{} \\
{}+\left.\log e^{-\frac{\alpha}{2z}}+\log\left(\frac{z}{e^{-\frac{\alpha}{2z}}}+1+\frac{z^2}{2e^{\frac{\alpha}{2z}}}+o\left(\frac{z^2}{e^{-\frac{\alpha}{2z}}}\right)\right)\right]={}
{}=\lim_{z\to0^+}z\left[-\frac{\alpha}{2z}-\log\left(z+\frac{z^2-2z+e^{-\frac{\alpha}{z}}}{2}+o\left(z^2-2z+e^{-\frac{\alpha}{z}}\right)\right)\right.+{} \\
{}+\left.\underbrace{\log\left(\frac{z}{e^{-\frac{\alpha}{2z}}}+1+\frac{z^2}{2e^{\frac{\alpha}{2z}}}+o\left(\frac{z^2}{e^{-\frac{\alpha}{2z}}}\right)\right)}_{\text{Goes to zero since the argument is $1+o(1)$.}}\right]={}
{}=\lim_{z\to0^+}z\left[-\frac{\alpha}{2z}-\log e^{-\frac{\alpha}{z}}-\log\left(\frac{z}{e^{-\frac{\alpha}{z}}}+\frac{z^2-2z+e^{-\frac{\alpha}{z}}}{2e^{-\frac{\alpha}{z}}}+\frac{1}{e^{-\frac{\alpha}{z}}}o\left(z^2-2z+e^{-\frac{\alpha}{z}}\right)\right)\right].
\end{multline*}

The first two terms give me a $\frac\alpha2$, and the rest should have a finite limit ($-\log\frac12$). So I would get the limit is $1+\frac\alpha2$. But I have two things giving me doubts:

- An older version of the notes and the pdf give this limit as $1+\alpha$, and the newer version (linked above) of the notes gives $\alpha$;
- I'm suspicious about that last small-o with the exponential under it: it does go to zero right?

So is this all correct or is there something not quite right about it?

**Update**

I just realized that:

1. No, that thing in general doesn't tend to zero, since if we multiply and divide by the small-$o$'s argument it becomes an infinitesimal fraction times $\frac{z^2-2z+e^{-\frac{\alpha}{z}}}{e^{-\frac{\alpha}{z}}}$ which goes to infinity;
2. The small-$o$ in the other logarithm has an infinite as its argument.

So I will start over. Now the expansion for the first logarithm is a huge mess, so I calculated a few terms with Wolfram ([1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z-1%2B1%2B%28z%5E2-2z%2Be%5E%28-alpha%2Fz%29%29%2F2-%28z%5E2-2z%2Be%5E%28-alpha%2Fz%29%29%5E2%2F8%2B%28z%5E2-2z%2Be%5E%28-alpha%2Fz%29%29%5E3%2F16-5%28z%5E2-2z%2Be%5E%28-alpha%2Fz%29%29%5E4%2F128) and [2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=7%28z%5E2-2z%2Be%5E%28-alpha%2Fz%29%29%5E5%2F512)) and, admitting I didn't mis-sum those messes, it should collapse into $\frac{7}{16}z^5+o(z^5)$, hence:

\begin{multline*}
\lim_{z\to0^+}\left[-z\log\left(z-1+\sqrt{1+e^{-\frac{\alpha}{z}}+z^2-2z}\right)+z\log\left(z+\sqrt{e^{-\frac{\alpha}{z}}+z^2}\right)\right]={} \\
{}=\lim_{z\to0^+}z\left[-\log\left(\frac{7}{16}z^5+o(z^5)\right)+\log z+\log\left(1+\sqrt{\frac{e^{-\frac{\alpha}{z}}}{z^2}+1}\right)\right]={} \\
{}=\lim_{z\to0^+}z\left[-\log\frac{7z^5}{16}-\log\left(1+o(1)\right)+\log z+\log\left(1+1+\frac{e^{-\frac{\alpha}{z}}}{2z^2}\right)\right]={} \\
{}=\lim_{z\to0^+}\left[-z\log\frac{7}{16}-5z\log z-z\log(1+o(1))+z\log z+z\log(2+o(1))\right]=0.
\end{multline*}

Is this huge mess right now? So my limit is 1 from the square roots plus 0 from the logarithms, thus 1. No $\alpha$. So it seems the whole thing in the notes is completely falling apart, because the proof that $u$ has no limit at the origin is now a non-proof, and even discontinuity with that $u(0,0,0)=2$ claimed by the notes is torn apart by the simple remark that:

$$u(0,0,0)=\int_0^1\frac{\tau}{\sqrt{0^2+0^2+(0-\tau)^2}}\mathrm{d}\tau=\int_0^2\frac{\tau}{|\tau|}\mathrm{d}\tau=\int_0^1\operatorname{sgn}\tau\mathrm{d}\tau=\int_0^1\mathrm{d}\tau=1.$$

So am I making any mistake in the above or are the notes full of errors?

**Extras: computing the ugly integral**

First of all I will get rid of the $z$ axis so as to always have a strictly positive denominator. It is easy to verify that for $z\in(0,1]$ $u(0,0,z)$ gives a diverging integral. After all, the denominator has a zero in a place ($\tau=z$) where the numerator doesn't, and it's an absolute-value type of zero, so order one, so non-integrable. Let's see the origin. Wait, I've already done it above. So for $z\notin[0,1]$ we proceed as follows:

\begin{align*}
u(0,0,z)={}&\int_0^1\frac{\tau}{\sqrt{0^2+0^2+(z-\tau)^2}}\mathrm{d}\tau=\int_0^1\frac{\tau}{|z-\tau|}\mathrm{d}\tau={} \\
{}={}&\begin{cases}
\int_0^1\frac{\tau}{\tau-z} & z<0 \\
-\int_0^1\frac{\tau}{\tau-z} & z>1 \\
\end{cases}=\begin{cases}
\int_0^1\frac{\tau-z}{\tau-z}\mathrm{d}\tau+z\cdot\int_0^1\frac{1}{\tau-z}\mathrm{d}\tau & z<0 \\
-\int_0^1\frac{\tau-z}{\tau-z}\mathrm{d}\tau-z\cdot\int_0^1\frac{1}{\tau-z}\mathrm{d}\tau & z>1
\end{cases}={} \\
{}={}&\begin{cases}
1+z\log|\tau-z|\Big|_0^1 & z<0 \\
-1-z\log|\tau-z|\Big|_0^1 & z>1
\end{cases}=\begin{cases}
1+z\log(1-z)-z\log(-z) & z<0 \\
-1-z\log(z-1)+z\log(z) & z>1 \\
\end{cases}={} \\
{}={}&\begin{cases}
1+z\log(1-\frac1z) & z<0 \\
-1-z\log(1-\frac1z) & z>1 \\
\end{cases}=\operatorname{sgn}(1-z)\cdot\left(1+z\log\left(1-\frac1z\right)\right).
\end{align*}

Let us now get out of the $z$ axis:

\begin{align*}
u(x,y,z)={}&\int_0^1\frac{\tau}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+(\tau-z)^2}}\mathrm{d\tau}={} \\
{}={}&\int_0^1\frac{\tau-z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+(\tau-z)^2}}+z\cdot\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+(\tau-z)^2}}\mathrm{d}\tau={} \\
{}\underset{\substack{\Big| \\ t=\frac{z-\tau}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}}{=}{\hspace{-.6cm}}&\sqrt{x^2+y^2+(\tau-z)^2}\Big|_0^1-z\cdot\int_{\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}^{\frac{z-1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\mathrm{d}t={} \\
{}={}&\sqrt{x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2}-\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}-z\log(t+\sqrt{1+t^2})\Big|_{\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}^{\frac{z-1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}={} \\
{}={}&\sqrt{x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2}-\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}-{} \\
&{}+z\log\left(\frac{z-1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}+\sqrt{1+\frac{(z-1)^2}{x^2+y^2}}\right)+{} \\
&{}+z\log\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}+\sqrt{1+\frac{z^2}{x^2+y^2}}\right)={} \\
{}={}&\sqrt{x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2}-\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}-z\log\frac{z-1+\sqrt{x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2}}{z+\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}.
\end{align*}

Interestingly enough, if I substitute $t=\frac{\tau-z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ up there, I get the pdf's expression, the notes' expression having an extra term and a wrong log argument, and the limit above is much easier. But do those things actually differ by a constant? Naturally! Here is the difference:

\begin{multline*}
\log(\tau-z+\sqrt{x^2+y^2+(\tau-z)^2})-(-\log(z-\tau+\sqrt{x^2+y^2+(z-\tau)^2}))={} \\
{}=\log((\tau-z+\sqrt{x^2+y^2+(\tau-z)^2})(z-\tau+\sqrt{x^2+y^2+(z-\tau)^2})))={} \\
{}=\log(x^2+y^2+(z-\tau)^2-(z-\tau)^2)=\log(x^2+y^2+z^2),
\end{multline*}

which is constant in $\tau$!

Comment: great latex skills +1

Comment: That's what I got with 3 years of taking notes in LaTeX -- and I study maths, so tons of formulas. :)